# Is there a way to see the changes in a file's previous commit while editing in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'm looking for a way to show the changes made in a previous commit so that it looks as if the file was just changed locally, with [line highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz9Vm.png) or changes shown on the same document.

I know that I can see the previous commit's changes with **Git** -> **Show History**, but I'd like to be able to see the new changes and previous commit changes in the same document if possible.